# Need unique details from MySQL table related to Chat message using query

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

i am using a MySQL database to store chat messages where my SQL table looks like this

```
id  sent_by    message  read    received_by created_at          updated_at
786 6           Hi      0       1           2018-04-26 13:00:15 2018-04-26 13:00:15
774 211         Hello   1       6           2018-04-26 12:20:25 2018-04-26 12:59:59
772 1           hi      1       6           2018-04-26 12:19:28 2018-04-26 13:00:14
```

This above data came to me with a result of this below query:

```
SELECT *
      FROM `enrich_chat_message` 
      WHERE id IN (SELECT MAX(id) AS id
      FROM `enrich_chat_message`  
      WHERE received_by=6 OR sent_by=6
             GROUP BY sent_by) 
ORDER BY created_at DESC
```

But i want to have records like this

```
id  sent_by    message  read    received_by     chat_with       created_at          updated_at
786 6           Hi      0       1               1           2018-04-26 13:00:15 2018-04-26 13:00:15
774 211         Hello   1       6               211         2018-04-26 12:20:25 2018-04-26 12:59:59
```

Here in the **above desired output** i have added a new column `chat_with` a unique column which shows a unique value from `sent_by` and `received_by`. The "6" is my own current user name from which a user is loggedin.

So i want to use this to display all the chats in the DESC order of chat. And i don't want the data to be repeated here. Like `1` should not be repeated in `chat_with`.

Looking for any suggestions to improve the query.

Thank you! (in advance)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```
SELECT emc.*, 
       (CASE WHEN emc.received_by = 6 THEN emc.sent_by ELSE emc.received_by END) as chat_with
FROM `enrich_chat_message` emc
WHERE emc.id IN (SELECT MAX(emc2.id) AS id
                 FROM `enrich_chat_message` emc2 
                 WHERE 6 IN (emc2.received_by, emc2.sent_by)
                 GROUP BY (CASE WHEN emc2.received_by = 6 THEN emc2.sent_by ELSE emc2.received_by END)
                )
ORDER BY emc.created_at DESC;
```

The purpose of the `CASE` expression is to get the *other* user.

Comment: I tried this query but its saying there is some `emc2.received_by` not found in field list error.